# Is this a typo in Section 1.8.1 Mathematics for Computer Science?

Tags: proof-explanation

[image]

Am I completely mistake or is it suppose to say $n^2$ is a multiple of 2 and therefore $n$ must be a multiple of 4?

This is from MIT's [Mathematics for Computer Science](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring17/mcs.pdf)

Comment: Generally: If $m,n$ are positive integers and $m^{1/n}$ is not an integer then $m^{1/n}$ is irrational. Proved by  a similar method.

Comment: What makes you think this is a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is correct. The point is that $2d^2=n^2$ implies $n^2$ is even, and only even numbers square to give an even number, so $n$ much be even, so $n^2$ is then actually a multiple of $4$.

Comment: This makes sense thanks

Answer (score 3):

No.  $6^2$ is a multiple of $2$ but $6$ is not a multiple of $4$.  If $n=2k$ then for sure $n^2=4k^2$.  So, MIT is right.